# Change ImageView's tint color in UIButton based on state

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uiimageview

I have a `UIButton` in the storyboard which displays only an image no text. Its type is system. The image's tint color needs to be changed when the button is tapped. How do I do this using `UIButton's` state config?

I have tried to `setImage` in the code for different states like below but could not get it to work. Thanks

```
setImage(UIImage(named: "test")?.applying(tintColor: .red), for: .highlighted)
setImage(UIImage(named: "test")?.applying(tintColor: .blue), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below code:-

```
@IBAction func onClickButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
 sender.imageView.image = sender.imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    if sender.isSelected || sender.isHighlighted{
        sender.imageView.tintColor = .red
    }else{
         sender.imageView.tintColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Follow the below steps plus your already done work:
1) Go to Images.xcassets and select your image i.e test
2) Click on attribute inspector on the right hand side of xcode
3) Change Render as option from "Default" to "Template Image"
4) Run again and test
```

Refer the image for the details[image: this image will shows the attributed inspector render option]

Comment: this worked too but I would prefer to do the same in the code. Thanks